# How do I print the root sign in Python?

Tags: python, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I tried this:

```
print u"\u221A"
```

But it won't work in Python.

Can someone say me how to do this in python? I need it to show what I have done.

Comment: Do you *really* think "won't work" explains *anything*?

Comment: Works for me (Ubuntu 10.04/Python 2.6). You have to be a lot more specific for others to be able to help.

Answer (score 5):

```
print u"\u221A".encode('utf-8')
```

Assuming by "won't work", you mean you're getting the UnicodeEncodeError I get running your code in interactive mode. Your terminal's encoding may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `LANG` environment variable as well:

```
% export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
% python -c 'print u"\u221a"'
√

% export LANG=en_US.ASCII     
% python -c 'print u"\u221a"'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u221a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: yes, it's is working in my python IDLE too, but when I use cmd it won't work and when I trie to make an exe of it with py2exe it gives the same fault

Answer (score 1):

Is the following the desired behavior?

```
wanderso@araran:~$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u"\u221A"
√
```

Without knowing the error message you're getting, some things to check would be whether or not you can print other unicode characters using the method you have in your terminal. If not, your problem is that you're probably not configured for unicode.

Comment: yes, it's is working in my python IDLE too, but when I use cmd it won't work and when I trie to make an exe of it with py2exe it gives the same fault

Answer (score 0):

You really should have explained what happened when you tried it. This is what happened when I tried it on Python 2.7 using Ubuntu's Gnome terminal program.

```
√
```

Comment: what env are you running?  On my Linux machine in xterm I get the UnicodeEncodeError without specifying an encoding.

Comment: yes, it's is working in my python IDLE too, but when I use cmd it won't work and when I trie to make an exe of it with py2exe it gives the same fault

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to print it to a document on Python 3.5 (I just used a for loop that when it found a character [\u221a] it appended it to a second result variable [in the form of a previously empty list] then printed the first to the console and the second [after joining it to a string of course] to the document), but when I printed it to a console, it worked just fine.